# HIve query to find maximum value

Tags: hadoop, hive, hiveql

I have below data I want to fetch the latest partition time for each ID

> ```
> ID       time
> 12  10038446  201705102100
> 13  10038446  201706052100
> 14  10038446  201706060000
> 15  10038446  201706060100
> 16  10103517  201705101700
> 17  10103517  201705102100
> 18  10103517  201706052100
> 19  10103517  201706060100
> 20  10124464  201701310100
> 21  10124464  201702210500
> 22  10124464  201702220500
> 23  10124464  201703062100
> 24  10124464  201705102100
> 25  10124464  201706052100
> 26  10124464  201706060100
> ```

Output I am expecting as below

```
15  10038446  201706060100
19  10103517  201706060100
26  10124464  201706060100
37  1019933 201706052100
```

How can I achieve this using Hive query?

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
select ID, time
from
(
  select 
    ID, 
    time, 
    row_number() over (partition by ID order by time desc) as time_rank
  from table_name
 ) x
where time_rank = 1
group by ID, time
```

without subquery (lower hive version), temporary table is one option.

```
create table tmp_table as
select 
  ID, 
  time, 
  row_number() over (partition by ID order by time desc) as time_rank
from table_name;

select ID, time
from tmp_table
where time_rank = 1
group by ID, time;

drop table tmp_table;
```

Comment: I am using lower version of hive where it does not support subqueries, Any other alternative ?

Comment: well, one option is to create temporary table for the data made by subquery, and then select from it.

Comment: Can you please suggest me on doing this

Comment: @Ganesh I added query for not using subqueries.

Comment: I tried your query, I am getting **ok failed: parseexception line 5:20 missing from at '(' near '(' in subquery source line 5:21 cannot recognize input near 'partition' 'by' 'id' in subquery source** I am using hive 0.10.0 version

Answer (score 0):

Use simple aggregation:

```
select  id, max(time) as time
  from table
group by id
order by id; --order if necessary
```

Demo with your dataset:

```
select id, max(time) as time 
from
table
group by id

OK
10038446        201706060100
10103517        201706060100
10124464        201706060100
Time taken: 30.66 seconds, Fetched: 3 row(s)
```

Comment: I tried the same earlier, It does not gave expected result, Instead, it gives complete result

Comment: I casted to max(CAST(r.nominaltime as BIGINT)), But same result

Comment: I am currently using hive 0.10.0 which does not support sub queries- Correct me If I am wrong

Comment: You do not need it because you have table with data. Just replace s subquery with your table like in my previous query